# How to pass weights and mask to weighted_masked_objective in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am wondering how can I compute a pixel-wise weighted loss for image segmentation. For each image I have a ground-truth mask and a weighted mask to give more importance to certain pixels in an image. Note that, my weighted mask is unique for each image so I can not pass this mask in a user defined loss function as an input. I can see a function ["weighted_masked_objective"](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/58fd1f0589d33aeb33c4129cfedfb7737495efc0/keras/engine/training_utils.py#L352) in keras/engine/training_utils.py which can handle a mask but I din not find any way to pass weighted mask to that function.

Is there any way to pass weighted mask to a loss function as part of standard input parameters e,g. y_true, y_pred?

Comment: Have you ever solved this?